# How to fix flash of theme-switching on page-reload? (Mantine v7.1.2 - NextJS)

Tags: next.js, reload, page-refresh, mantine, flashing

I'm using Mantine v7.1.2 with NextJS.I've already added this code to my `_app.tsx`, but the flash of dark-theme on page-refresh still persists. How do I fix this? Thank you so much in advance

`<MantineProvider theme={defaultTheme} defaultColorScheme='light'`>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Was surprised to see this question downvoted. Mantine does indeed do a flash of default browser color-scheme after it injects the css but before the javascript adds the `data-mantine-color-scheme="value"` attribute to the `html` tag.

The workaround I used was to set `data-mantine-color-scheme="light"` (or `dark` or `auto`) manually on the `<html ...` tag to avoid the flash.

Comment: This did it for me. I wrapped the color scheme in `<Head>...</Head>` from `next/head`, and it flashed. Adding this to the html fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Mantine team provides templates for popular environments on their document. There are not enough details in your question but I can suggest you to check out the templates and compare with your project.

Templates listed [here](https://mantine.dev/getting-started/).

Next app route and Next page route, both of them available.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the AppRouter adding `defaultColorScheme` to the `<ColorSchemeScript />` works.

Like this:

```
<ColorSchemeScript defaultColorScheme="dark" />
```

Comment: Interestingly, this did not work for me (app router) when wrapping this in `<Head>...</Head>` from `next/head`. If I use the regular `<head>...</head>` it works. Next gives a linting error though.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar bug while developing my project. You have to set the colorsSchemeScript theme to "light", if you are using light theme. Just adding "light" to MantineProvider's defaultColorScheme will still flicker. It worked for me.

```
<Head>
   <ColorSchemeScript defaultColorScheme="light" />
</Head>
```